# Transit Visa for Philippine Passport holder in hongkong

Tags: visas, transit, airports

I am a Philippine passport holder with a Japan Resident Card flying back from Manila back to Japan. I have a 2 hour layover in Hongkong airport, do I need an airport transit visa. I am only on 2 hours layover changing to another airplane.

Answer (score 2):

For a Philippine citizen with residence in Japan, returning to Japan, Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify that your documents are sufficient to travel, says only this about transiting in Hong Kong SAR:

> VISA NOT REQUIRED.